# Is there exists some endpoint online to test ElasticSearch?

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

Does there exist some online endpoint to test *ElasticSearch*?
I know of pages where I can interactively query an *ElasticSearch* database...
Simply put, I would like to knock to some endpoint from my machine (using cURL).

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Why you can't install ES? it's awesome!

Comment: I can, however I would like to have already existing databse to query.

Comment: Try this tutorial which tells you how to load some sample data: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-load-dataset.html